# Where can I find Core Image Fun House App

Tags: xcode, ios5, core-image

I know this isn't a technical question, but I'm hoping other developers here can help me.  I'm getting started on a project that will require leveraging CIFilters and I know in previous versions of Xcode, Core Image Fun House was bundled in.  I can't find it anywhere on my machine and I've also downloaded the additional developer tools from the Apple Dev site.

Is Core Image Fun House not supported and distributed anymore?  If not, does anyone have another app where I can mess around with the various CIFilter options before writing the actual code?  That will likely speed up developing and make it less guess and check.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You can find the iOS app here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CIFunHouse/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013431

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://cmwolfe.blogspot.com/2012/08/core-image-fun-house-on-mountain-lion.html) shows you where to get it and how to compile it for a modern version of the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's been deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/FunHouse/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously, the link posted by @TOMATO is for the deprecated version.  The new version, and other WWDC 2013 code, is available via these steps:

- Navigate to :https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/resources/
- Click on WWDC 2013 Sample Code
- (Log in)
- Download iOS_CIFunHouse.zip and iOS_DeHaze.zip

Credit to the Core Image evangelist, Allan Schaffer.

Comment: From the names of the files, those appear to be iOS only, altho they could probably be translated back to OSX without *too* much trouble.